# Transfer a received array to memory in real-time

Tags: memory, dma

I'm using STM32F407.
I save the data read from a microphone via the HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA API using a circular buffer. I store the received data in an `int16_t data_i2s[SAMPLE_COUNT]` array.

Using a circular buffer, if I don't move the data to a 'safe' location in time, it will be overwritten every time the buffer size is exceeded.

I think there are two solutions:

1. Every time the `HAL_I2S_RxCpltCallback` function is triggered, I move/store half of the circular buffer to another array or to memory.
2. I don't move 'data blocks' as in case 1) but I move each sample received in real time into another array (directly into an SRAM address chosen by me before debugging).

I want to realise this second possibility, but I don't really know the syntax/command to execute it.

In particular, I previously used a for loop to move each element from an array to the SRAM, but here I don't know how to do it and I think that was an 'end of read' solution, i.e. when you have all the data stored in the array and are no longer receiving.

Comment: You can of course move the data somewhere else, but what if that "somewhere else" fills up? How much RAM does your microcontroller have?

Comment: "HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA" -- that's some specific company's API.  Please _edit your question_ to say what microcontroller you're using, and if it's on an eval board, what eval board.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using STM32F407

Comment: Individual samples are just data-blocks of size 1. Can you change how full the buffer has to be, before the interrupt is triggered? On some microcontrollers you can set it to trigger the interrupt as soon as the buffer isn't empty. You should still transfer all the data in the buffer, using a loop, in case the interrupt got delayed (e.g. because a higher-priority interrupt happened at the same time)